# Bootstrap - Button group of checkboxes don't toggle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Can I apply Bootstrap's data-toggle to a group of checkboxes?

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
<div id="Answer76" class="Answer FirstAnswer">       
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="btn" type="checkbox">A
    </label>
</div>
<div id="Answer77" class="Answer">        
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="btn active" type="checkbox">B
    </label>
</div>
<div id="Answer78" class="HwSxAnswer ">        
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="btn" type="checkbox">C
    </label>
</div>
```

I can get if I change my  elements to be buttons the toggle effect works. I need to use checkboxes. Is this possible?

Comment: [tag:bootstrap] != [tag:twitter-bootstrap]. Please learn the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. Even if it would be possible, checkboxes can't be styled freely on most browsers, so they wouldn't look like buttons. This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1161) may possibly help you.